# How to use TableView inside viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, tableview

In the storyboard I have added a table view to my view controller, I have ctrl dragged the TableView to to the Viewcontroller and connected "delegate" and "datasource". In the (.h) file I have added `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` but when I run the app I just get a  SIGABRT error (?) and the app crashes. What should I do?

Comment: th error: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: Have you implemented the required methods of UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: No, I have not @ColdLogic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So far so good, you just have to implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in your implementation file.

Required functions are as follows;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [regions count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region.timeZoneWrappers count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region name];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]];
    }
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    TimeZoneWrapper *timeZoneWrapper = [region.timeZoneWrappers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timeZoneWrapper.localeName;
    return cell;
}
```

[Here's the link for the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)